# Azure App Service API Deployment requires a restart

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I use the **Deploy Azure App Service**  VSTS task to deploy an asp dotnet core API to an Azure API app using the *Publish using Web Deploy* option. The task runs without any errors but somehow I have to **restart** the API to get the new version.

Is that intended? Is there any flag that I can set to immediately get the deployment "live"? As a workaround I can add a restart task but I hope there is another way....

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. I made a test with this projects https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-api/app-service-api-dotnet-get-started, and remain the default value of the Azure App Service Deploy step/task. What's the result if you deploy API App with this project (ToDoListDataAPI)?

Comment: actually I am having similar issue - after I publish update to API, my client app seems to be using old API version, but when I run unit tests (they use new API version) - but for me restart did not help

Comment: I have the same issue. Wondering if someone knows how to fix it. Only restart works for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using App Service Local Cache? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-local-cache

If you are you will need to remove WEBSITE_LOCAL_CACHE_OPTION = Always property of your web app to have your publish show right away.

Otherwise you can always use a deployment slot to test your app before swapping in production.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't use the app service local cache but its good to know that there is a cache :)

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why the deploy doesn't show right away but I can recommend you use a staging deployment slot and then swap into production. The swaping process is not the same as deploy, the warm up phase should fix your problem. [doc](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2017/05/16/deploy-app-azure-app-service/)